# Django add files to model with Dropzone

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, file

I have a django bootstrap project and I want to add files to my Django model via a Dropzonejs.js. My problem is that the files don't get a name in the model. They are just blank files without any links/content to them.

[image]

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models


class Studyplan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File, blank=True, null=True)
```

This is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def teacher_assignment_add_files(request, assignment_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.POST.get('Assignment-File')
        file = File(file=file)
        file.save()
        assignment = Assignment(id=assignment_id)
        assignment.files.add(file.id)
        return redirect('teacher-detail-assignment', id = assignment_id)
```

The Dropzonejs form:

```
<form class="dropzone" action="{% url 'teacher_assignment_add_file' OBJECTID %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <span class="dz-message">Dra filer hit för att ladda upp</span>
</form>
```

Comment: You might want to consider to use FileField + django-storages to handle file storage in Django

Comment: On the admin paag

Comment: On the admin page everything works fine! Its just in the bootstrap it dosen't work

Comment: Django already created some widgets to handle model fields on admin page, you could follow that to implement drag and drop. With dropzone, you have to know what is the name of the input element on dropzone. Use that name in the backend to get the file content then use some django utils to store the file.

Comment: Can you give an example with the code I posted above? I can't seem to figure it out inside the bootstrap

Comment: Is the view correct for a FileField? Because the post request goes through, the file just don't come with the request

Comment: I can't say thing because there are not much information for me to find a clue. Maybe something need you to provide: `file = request.POST.get('Assignment-File')` are you sure that the file has sent to server? Could you update your answer to clarify where File class come from? Could you also provide Assignment model code?

Comment: I Tried: <form class="dropzone" action="{% url 'teacher_assignment_add_file' OBJECTID %}" method="POST">
                          {% csrf_token %}
                          <span class="dz-message" name="Assignment-File">Dra filer hit för att ladda upp</span>
                        </form>

Comment: It suppose to be like this. `<form class="dropzone" action="{% url 'teacher_assignment_add_file' OBJECTID %}" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %} <span class="dz-message">Dra filer hit för att ladda upp</span> <input  name="Assignment-File" type="file"></form>`. The uploaded file will be put into that input and when the form sent to your backend, we can get that via `request.FILES['Assignment-File']`.

Comment: dosen't work, it just adds another field underneath that is the input field.

Comment: could you provide the information which I've mentioned above? For now I don't know what is File class and what's the data type of `files` field of Assignment model

Comment: Its a FileField so it can take all kinds of files. Check this new post I made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029052/i-cant-get-the-values-from-django-dropzone-into-view

Comment: Yeah, try this. Instead of read the file from POST, switch to use FILES instead. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

Comment: My problem is that I can't get the name into the actual request, so I tried changing it to files but that didn't change it, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: No, I think you should setup DEBUG mode and run your app line by line to see the file uploaded or not before you can save it into database.